# How to wait for file scanning finished before starting the launcher app

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an Android launcher application, and I would like to play some intro video before the launcher starts. Knowing that playing video directly from assets or raw folder does not work on some devices, I include the video file in assets folder, and let the app copy the video file to SD card before playing it.

However, since launcher is always the first application to be started upon bootup, there is a media scanning process right after the bootup. So the problem is when the launcher is started, the SD card file system may still being scanned and not ready to be accessed, therefore the video cannot be played.

Any suggestions and comments are appreciated!

Comment: Do you find the solution? I want to load some images from sdcard, but when sdcard has lot of files and mounted, I could not get images at the beginning. I have to wait for a very long time. Is there any way I could get these images without scan all finished?

Answer (score 0):

You may copy the file to the stream returned by [openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and then use [openFileInput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29) to play it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.
But if the sd file system not ready (still scanning), I cannot read/write file to sd card, is it?

Comment: openFileOutput() will write to internal memory instead of SD.